# The folder shows 3 files but when run the script in CMD it shows extra ` . ` and ` .. `?

Tags: perl

I got confused by below situation, am I supposed to get `Size = 3` instead of `5` as inside my folder only got 3 files? Where did the `.` and `..` came from?

**Code:**

```
my $directory = 'c:\modules\SFTP\New';

opendir(DIR,$directory);
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
foreach(@files){
  print $_,"\n";
}
my $size = @files;

print "Size - $size\n";
```

**Run the perl:**

[image: It shows 5 records instead of 3]

Inside my folder only got 3 files, but it print out 5 records in CMD. Why is there `.` and `..` show in the cmd?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thank you minitech and chilemagic. So `.` and `..` is current directory and parent directory.

Additional question : How can I show the files only, so that I can get the `size = 3`. If there is no other way, perhaps I should done it in manual way to deduct it.

Comment: `.` is the current directory, and `..` is the parent directory. You can check for them specifically when printing and subtract two for an accurate count.

Comment: `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory. If you `cd` into that directory and type `dir` you'll see them too.

Comment: @minitech Thank you. Do you mean just manually minus 2 from the count?

Comment: @thor_that_new_in_programming: Yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` and `..` are references to the current and parent directories, respectively.

It's a rather standard thing to filter them out from a [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) call:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; 

my $directory = 'c:\modules\SFTP\New';

my @files = do {
    opendir my $dh, "$directory";
    grep {! /^\.+$/} readdir($dh);
};
```

Or if you're ok with full path information, you can also use a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), which will not include `.` and `..`.

```
my @files = glob("$directory\\*")
```

Comment: `Parentheses missing around "my" list at filename.pl line 8.` `:P`

Comment: Bah, stupid ambiguous warning.  I'd rather avoid that by putting parenthesis around the directory.  Alternatively, using an `or die` would also remove the warning.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider filtering those out.  I often use an approach like this when I'm collecting a file / dir list from a `readdir` into an array

```
my @dir_contents = grep { !/^[.]+$/ } readdir($directory);
```

**Edit to answer your edit**

If you want only files, you can use the `-f` test in perl.  So, perhaps loop through your directory structure, skipping over the '.' and '..' and anything that's a directory, capturing the rest in an array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $directory = 'c:\modules\SFTP\New';
my @files;

opendir( my $dir_handle, $dir );
while (my $file = readdir($dir_handle) ) {
    next if $file =~ /^[.]+$/;
    push( @files, $file ) if ( -f $file );
}
my $size = @files;
print "Size - $size\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

[Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) is much nicer than readdir, it even `autodie`s for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Path::Tiny qw/ tempdir path /;
my $dad = tempdir;
path( $dad, 'roy' )->touchpath->spew('first');
path( $dad, 'g' )->spew('second');
path( $dad, 'biv' )->spew('third');
print "$_\n" for $dad->children;
$dad->remove_tree;
print "$_\n" for $dad->children;
__END__
$ perl path-tiny-children-three.pl
C:/...Temp/q1gU2kX7kZ/biv
C:/...Temp/q1gU2kX7kZ/g
C:/...Temp/q1gU2kX7kZ/roy
Error opendir on 'C:/...Temp/q1gU2kX7kZ': No such file or directory at path-tiny-children-three.pl line 10.
```

[File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) is more memorable than glob, makes a fantastic companion to Path::Tiny

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule qw/ find rule /;
use Path::Tiny qw/ tempdir path /;
my $dad = tempdir;
path( $dad, 'roy' )->touchpath->spew('first');
path( $dad, 'g' )->spew('second');
path( $dad, 'biv' )->spew('third');

print "$_\n" for find( file => maxdepth => 1 => in => $dad );

$dad->remove_tree;
__END__
C:/...Temp/2Ho4c_jBQy/biv
C:/...Temp/2Ho4c_jBQy/g
C:/...Temp/2Ho4c_jBQy/roy
```